# ServiceStack/TypeScript: The typescript-ref ignores namespaces (this causing duplicates)

Tags: rest, typescript, servicestack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am learning NativeScript + Angular2 with ServiceStack in C# as the backend.

For the app, I generated TypeScript classes using the `typescript-ref` command, for use with the `JsonServiceClient` in ServiceStack:

```
>typescript-ref http://192.168.0.147:8080 RestApi
```

It all looked sweet and dandy, until I discovered that it seems to ignore that the ServiceStack Services and Response DTOs are in different namespaces on the .NET side:

[image]

I have different branches of services, where the handlers for each service might differ slightly between the branches. This works well in ServiceStack, the Login and handlers work just as expected.

So, on the app/NativeScript/Angular2-side, I used the `typescript-ref` and generated the `restapi.dtos.ts`. The problem is it skips the namespace difference and just creates duplicate classes instead (from VSCode):

[image]

The backend WS in ServiceStack is built in this "branched" fashion so I don't have to start different services on different ports, but rather gather all of them on one port and keep it simple and clear.

Can my problem be remedied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never rely on .NET namespaces in your public facing Services Contract. It's supported in .NET Clients but not in any other language which [requires that each DTO be uniquely named](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#limitations).

In general your DTOs should be unique within your entire SOA boundary so that there's only 1 `Test` DTO which maps to a single schema definition which ensures that when it's sent through a Service Gateway, resolved through Service Discovery, published to a MQ Server, etc it only maps to a single DTO contract.

Comment: Right, I have to rethink this then. Do you know if there is a way to host multiple APIs on same port, not using a classic webserver for reverse proxy? I'm selfhosting.

Comment: @Ted Not on the same port, so you'd need to use a reverse proxy if you want multiple instances to appear from the same host.

Comment: Alright, thx. Maybe it would be a great future feature to be able to start one AppHost on one port, but define multiple APIs, so the AppHost could specify more than one assembly in the constructor, or something like it? So instead of: `public AppHost(IModuleController moduleController, IContactModule contactModule) : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(AppHost).Assembly)`, maybe something like `AddAssemblyWithServices(Assembly assembly, string prefix)` where `prefix` prefixes all the services in the assembly, so `/api/<prefix>/<service>` ? =)

Comment: @Ted You can specify [multiple dlls  in AppHost Constructor](http://docs.servicestack.net/modularizing-services). IMO routes should be explicitly on each Request DTO since it's part of the service contract, but there's also [Auto Route Generation Strategies](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#auto-route-generation-strategies) and ways to dynamically modify routes by [overriding GetRouteAttributes in your AppHost](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#customizing-defined-routes). Other feature requests can be added to [UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com) so interest can be measured.

Comment: OK, but inside each Assembly containing services, the DTOs/services must still have unique names (because its the same "service contract"?). So, in the case of `typeof(ServicesFromDll1).Assembly,   
typeof(ServicesFromDll2).Assembly`, service names in `ServicesFromDll1` cannot have any DTO etc with the same name is in `ServicesFromDll2`, as per your answer above?

Comment: @Ted Right there can only be 1 Request DTO with a single Implementation for the entire AppHost, that will never change. The multiple Assemblies lets you split your Service implementations across multiple assemblies. You should still only have the 1 Service Model project for the entire AppHost, which is what defines its public Service Contract.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. Then my feature request sort of still exists ;-) https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/33333031-support-multiple-api-service-contracts-on-the-sa

Comment: @Ted That can never happen, being able to [invoke a Service by sending an encapsulated Request DTO](http://docs.servicestack.net/architecture-overview#client-architecture) is fundamental to ServiceStack. [Request DTOs are what defines  your Service Contract](http://docs.servicestack.net/service-complexity-and-dto-roles#data-transfer-objects---dtos) and they can only have a single implementation. Your design need to change, if you want to support [multi tenancy](http://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy) the tenant should be included in the Request DTO.